# OpenGL slow with 3 frames

Tags: java, opengl, processing

I'm using processing, a great java dialect for working with graphics.
If i make multiple sketches (see it as multiple duplicates of the project to be able to run them at the same time) with the following code and run it:

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 400, OPENGL);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(0, 255, 0);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotateX(radians(45));
  rotateY(radians(45));
  rotateZ(radians(45));

  box(100);

  popMatrix();

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text(frameRate, 20, 40);
}
```

Then my framerate stays near 60 for every sketch.
[image: multiple sketches, framerate stays high]

What i need is multiple windows started from one sketch.
I do that as follow:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        PApplet.main(new String[] { "MyProcessingSketch", "0" });
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "MyProcessingSketch", "1" });
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "MyProcessingSketch", "2" });
    }


    public void setup() {

        size(800,600, OPENGL);
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0, 255, 0);

        pushMatrix();
        translate(width/2, height/2);
        rotateX(radians(45));
        rotateY(radians(45));
        rotateZ(radians(45));

        box(100);

        popMatrix();

        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text(frameRate, 20, 40);
    }
}
```

Now however my frameRate is getting really low:
[image: sloooow]

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this.
I tried setting Thread priority to max but that didn't help.

Here is some info that might help:
For the rest, ask if you need to know something and i will look into it.

Each **PApplet.main()** instantiates a new **PApplet** and store it in its local variable applet:
https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L10628

Also instantiates a new `JFrame` @ #L10614 :

```
Frame frame = new JFrame(displayDevice.getDefaultConfiguration());
```

And assign it to field frame @ #L10684 -> applet.frame = frame;

Method init() is called @ #L10757 -> applet.init();

At the end of it @ #L965, a new Thread is created & started:

```
thread = new Thread(this, "Animation Thread");
thread.start();
```

From that moment on, it's an alive & self-sustainable PApplet object.

---

edit:

I got a answer of Ben Fry, one of the 2 founders of Processing.

> This isn't a bug... it's out of scope for something we'd support with
>   Processing. Multi-threaded, multi-window OpenGL is a very complicated
>   undertaking, and you should be working directly with OpenGL for
>   something like that, controlling buffer swapping, etc.

It would be nice if someone could describe in detail what exactly has to be done.

Comment: This might be due to having "Wait for VBlank" enabled in your GPU driver and some unfortunate handling of the SwapBuffers in your program (maybe internally by processing itself, but I don't know enough about that). That could lead to the situation that it will wait for the VBlank for each window, limiting frame rate to half of monitor refresh rate for 2 windows, and a thrid for 3, and so on.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm sure they look into it someday :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a potential bug in the way the different opengl threads are handled in Processing, the comment from @derhass sounds reasonable. Could you open an issue in the github page (https://github.com/processing/processing/issues?state=open)? Thanks!